# Having issues with nib from ios_google_places_autocomplete

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

Thank you for viewing this page.

I have downloaded the following from GH: https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete

It uses a nib file to initiate a autocomplete feature within a ViewController (in the Main Storyboard.

- Issues

The following issues are hindering my progress;

1. I am unable to close the nib view using the X (or Stop button). The
   nib loads via ViewDidLoad, therefore every time it dismisses itself,
   it will be shown again.  I have attempted to do the following but it
   does not work.
2. When any cell is selected, I am unable to go back to the ViewController I originally navigated from. (same as point 1,
   however should happen once I select any of the cells).

   ```
   extension LocoSearch: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate {
   func placeSelected(place: Place) {
   println(place.description)
   println(place.id)

   var locoResult = PFUser.currentUser()
   locoResult["placeDesc"] = place.description
   locoResult["placeId"] = place.id
   locoResult.pin()

   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("locoDone", sender: self)
   }

     func placeViewClosed() {
   dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("locoDone", sender: self)
   })
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. To stop the autocomplete controller from loading every time the view loads, either remove it from `viewDidLoad` (and put it in a button click handler, for example), or if that's really where it belongs then perhaps use a [variable stored property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) to store the currently selected `Place` and only show the autocomplete controller if none exists.
2. `placeSelected` is the correct callback for handling selections. Perhaps you should dismiss the autocomplete view before performing the segue as you do in your close handler? Please link a Github project with this issue if you really can't get it working.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I had done point 1 via the button and this works a charm.  However, point 2 - would it not be a better user experience if the xib view closed once the user selected a cell.  If their a way to do this?

At present - I am on a 'settings' type page and unfortunately I am unable to trigger a cell to action this view which would be perfect.

Comment: As I said, please link an example project which is not working properly for you and I'll do my best to help.